# Как вызвать в пределах одного solution из одного проекта другой?

Tags: c#, проект

Требуется создать solution в VS на C# из двух проектов, один из которых использует другой. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как такое возможно? Видимо, тут стандартными средствами не обойтись, по-крайней мере у меня не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого в папке References необходимо указать ссылку на используемый вами проект.

Comment: И это ооооооооочень стандартные средства